# How to scrape javascript while using a webpage normally?

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I know very little about js and I'm trying to create a program that will get information about a browser based javascript game while I play it. I can't use a webdriver as I will be playing the game at the time.

When I inspect the js on google chrome and look at the console, I can see all the information that I want to work with but I don't know how I can save that to a file or access it at the time in order to parse it. Preferably I'd be able to do this with python as that's what I will use for my code that will handle the info once I have it.

Any help or a point in the right direction would be appreciated, thank you :)

ps, I'm on Windows if that's important

Answer (score 0):

hacking a game I see. Provided you are aware that what you are doing may diminish the validity of other's playtime as well as potentially committing a crime, I shall provide a solution:

You would need to get a piece of "sniffing" software which allows modifications.

The modifications are likely to be the addition of "Querystring" and "JSON" parsers to read the data traffic. At this point, you can begin learning how their particular system works, slowly replacing traffic with modified versions for your nefarious purposes.

"TCP Sniffing" includes creating a "RAW TCP SOCKET" in whatever language and then repeatedly "READ'ing / RECV'ing" from that socket. The socket MUST be bound TO THE SPECIFIC NETWORK INTERFACE CARD (NIC). Hint: "LOCALHOST" and "127.0.0.1" are NOT the addresses of any NIC.

You would then parse the data as a HTTP req/res stream, ensuring that you can read the contents of the frame correctly.

You would then be looking to either modify the contents of the POST body or the GET querystring. Either, depending on how the game designers designed their network system.

Comment: Ah, I think you misunderstood what I'm trying to achieve. I'm not looking to cheat in the game, just gather information on my gameplay and see how often I win and how often I end up in certain situations.

Comment: Would still likely require the same sophisticated setup ;) other than recording with a desktop recording software?